# Inverse of sets in product space

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I'm currently studying product topology(along with box topology). A problem that often comes up is to decide whether a given function is a homeomorphism or not. Bijectiveness usually isn't the hard part, continuity is. I solve these kind of problems by letting some basis element $\prod_{\alpha \in J}U_\alpha$, and seeing whether $f^{-1}\left(\prod_{\alpha \in J}U_\alpha\right)$ is open or not. A usual problem that I encounter is whether the following statement holds:

> Let $f:A\to \prod_{\alpha \in J}X_\alpha$ be a bijective function, and define $f(a)=(f_\alpha(a))_{\alpha\in J}$ where $f_\alpha:A \to X_\alpha$ for each $\alpha$. (This is the same setting as **Theorem 19.6** in Munkres) For $\prod_{\alpha \in J}X_\alpha$ equipped with product/box topology, do we always have
> $$f^{-1}\left(\prod_{\alpha \in J}U_\alpha \right)=\prod_{\alpha \in J}f_{\alpha}^{-1}(U_\alpha)$$
> where $U_\alpha$ is a subset(usually open, though) of $X_\alpha$?

I think the statement is true, and the reasoning is

> $$x \in f^{-1}\left(\prod_{\alpha \in J}U_\alpha \right) \iff f(x) \in \prod_{\alpha \in J}U_\alpha \iff f_\alpha(x) \in U_\alpha \quad \text{for}\quad\forall \alpha\in J$$ $$\iff x \in f_{\alpha}^{-1}(U_\alpha) \forall \alpha \in J \iff x\in \prod_{\alpha \in J}f_{\alpha}^{-1}(U_\alpha)$$

So, in my opinion the statement holds whenever whether $\prod_{\alpha \in J}X_\alpha$ is equipped with either box/product topology, whether $U_\alpha$'s are open or not, whether the index set $J$ is uncountable or not. Is this true?

Comment: What is $h_i$ ?

Comment: What is $h$? And what does $f$ have to do with all this? Please clarify the statement, and write all the details.

Comment: I believe that the OP wanted to say that $h$ is a function (just like $f$) which can be written as $(h_i(x))$ = $h(x)$ (just like $f_{\alpha})$

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Sorry, my bad. I messed up my indices and function names. $f_\alpha$ is the $\alpha$th component of the function.

Comment: @azif00 I fixed the indices and function name. Would the above make sense? I couldn't manage to elaborate to the fullest because I'm a beginner, and I have some difficulties understanding the terminology Munkres's Topology makes, such as J-tuples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f_\alpha:A\to X_\alpha$ for each $\alpha\in J$ and $f:A\to\prod_{\alpha\in J}X_\alpha$ is given by $f(x)=\bigl(f_\alpha(x)\bigr)_{\alpha\in J},$ then the following are, indeed, equivalent for any $x\in A,$ regardless of topology and regardless of whether $f$ is a bijection $A\to\prod_{\alpha\in J}X_\alpha$:

$$x\in f^{-1}\left(\prod_{\alpha\in J}U_\alpha\right)$$
$$f(x)\in\prod_{\alpha\in J}U_\alpha$$
$$\forall\alpha\in J,f_\alpha(x)\in U_\alpha$$
$$\forall\alpha\in J,x\in f_\alpha^{-1}(U_\alpha)$$

However, this last is clearly equivalent to $$x\in\bigcap_{\alpha\in J} f_\alpha^{-1}(U_\alpha).$$

Saying that $x\in\prod_{\alpha\in J}f_\alpha^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ is generally nonsensical, as $x$ is an element of $A,$ whereas $\prod_{\alpha\in J}f_\alpha^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ contains **tuples** of elements of $A.$ It will certainly be true is if $J$ is a singleton, though in that case we're simply claiming that $f^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}(U),$ so that isn't very enlightening.

Comment: Aha, so the right formula would be $$f^{-1}\left(\prod_{\alpha \in J}U_\alpha \right)=\bigcap_{\alpha \in J}f_{\alpha}^{-1}(U_\alpha)$$ right?

Comment: That's correct!

Comment: For example, consider $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2$ given by $$f(t)=(\cos t,\sin t),$$ let $U=\{x\in\Bbb R:x>0\},$ and $f^{−1}(U^2).$ Then $$f^{−1}_1(U)=\Bigl\{x\in\Bbb R:\exists n\in\Bbb Z\bigl((4n−1)\pi/2<x<(4n+1)\pi/2\bigr)\Bigr\}$$ and
$$f^{−1}_2(U)=\Bigl\{x\in\Bbb R:\exists n\in\Bbb Z\bigl(2n\pi<x<(2n+1)\pi\bigr)\Bigr\},$$ so by the formula, $$f^{−1}(U^2)=\Bigl\{x\in\Bbb R:\exists n\in Z\bigl(2n\pi<x<(4n+1)\pi/2\bigr)\Bigr\}.$$
Thus, $f(t)$ is in the first quadrant exactly when $t$ differs from an acute anticlockwise angle with the positive $x$-axis by $n$ full rotations about the origin.